# 5 sec is needed to process a simple soap request using savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsdl, savon

The goal is to connect to a 3rd party SOUP API provider. They have provided a WSDL definition.

The first thing that came to my mind is to use Savon gem. So I implemented it, the straightforward way, like below:

```
client = Savon.client do
    wsdl http://url_to_wsdl/
end

response = client.call(:some_supported_action) do
    message message
end
```

The response returns correctly. But I notice it was after 10 seconds. So, as usual, I blame the server first. So I do a packet capture on both ends. And the wiresharks results show that server responded in <200ms.

Then I did some research and some people says that remote WSDL might take some time to be downloaded by Savon. So I modified the code to use a local version:

```
client = Savon.client do
    wsdl Rails.root.join('config', 'local.xml')
end
```

Now, the time I need to get a response reduced to 5.x seconds. Maybe this is the result of one call lesser in Savon. But it is still slow.

Next, I also read that parsing WSDL could be slow. So I get rid of the WSDL entirely.

```
client = Savon.client do
    endpoint 'my_endpoint'
    namespace 'my_namespace'
    element_form_default :qualified
end
response = client.call('MethodName',
               soap_action: 'SoupActionName',
               message: message)
```

Without wsdl parsing, the response still takes 5 seconds. Further checking on WireShark Log, I notice that the outgoing packet is only sent roughly 5sec after client.call is called.

Finally, I switch to use 'http' instead of 'net_http' as the HTTP client. Make no different too. Still 5-6 seconds.

```
HTTPI POST request to my_url.com (http)
HTTPI POST request to my_url.com (net_http)
```

Additional info:

1. I am using savon 2.11 and rails 4.2.7
2. If I use a test tool, such as Boomerang Chrome App, it shows fast response from server, which matches the packet capture result. So it is very likely to be something specific to Savon internal processing.

Anyone has any idea why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which wasabi version do you use? Version 2.1.0 did have an performance regression.

Comment: @slowjack2k In my Gemfile.lock I see wasabi (3.5.0)

Comment: 5 secs. sounds like a kind of timeout. Did you try an ip address instead of domain name? Maybe it has to do with DNS or ipv6.

Comment: Bingo. I get a 100ms response after changing to IP address. I will check the root cause in that direction. Thanks man!

Comment: Iam using IP address, but still it takes 5 sec to get the response. Any inputs to this?